# Python- Expanded form of a number raised to the power of ten

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm pretty new to coding and I am trying to write a python script where a user enters an integer and it displays that integer in expanded form raised to the power of 10's.

Example: A user enters `643541` and the script outputs `643541 = (6x10^5 )+(4x10^4)+(3x10^3)+(5x10^2)+(4x10^1)+(1x10^0)`

This is my code

```
A = [7000, 400, 70,1]
cond = True
y = 0
i = 0
sizeArray = len(A)
for i in range(0, sizeArray-1):
    while cond == True:
        if A[i]%10 == 0:
            A[i] = A[i]/10
            y += 1

        else:
            cond = False
    print(y)
```

I tried working with a sample array to test the number of zero's but I don't know how i will be able to output the result as above.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform your input integer `643541` to an array of digits `[6,4,3,5,4,1]`. Then maintain a variable for the exponent. It will be decremented for each digit in the array

```
def function(num):
 digits = str(num) # convert number to string
 output = []
 for i, digit in enumerate(digits):
   output.append("(" + digit + "x10^" + str(len(digits)-i-1) + ")")
 return " + ".join(output)
```

Here `len(digits)-i-1` plays the role of the variable that maintains exponent value

Answer (score 2):

Every question like this deserves a solution using a list comprehension:

```py
>>> n = 123456
>>> '+'.join([ '({1}x10^{0})'.format(*t) for t in enumerate(str(n)[::-1]) ][::-1])
'(1x10^5)+(2x10^4)+(3x10^3)+(4x10^2)+(5x10^1)+(6x10^0)'
```

Explanation:

- `str(n)[::-1]` converts the number to a string and then reverses the string, giving the digits of the number, as strings, from least-significant to most-significant.
- `enumerate` returns pairs `t = (i, d)` where `i` is the index and `d` is the digit. Since the sequence is from least-significant to most-significant, the index equals the corresponding exponent of 10.
- `*t` unpacks `(i, d)` for `{0}` and `{1}` in the format string, so the result is like `({d}x10^{i})`.
- The `[::-1]` applied to the list comprehension reverses the results back into the right order.
- `'+'.join` joins those results together into a single string, with the + symbol between the parts.